# How to specify facebook scope with div login button?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web, shows:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

But when getting the code just above that for the button, the buttons is a `div` so there is no scope attribute..

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

So how do we specify permissions now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="public_profile,email" ...></div>
```